# Why does the chi squared distribution intersect the y axis at 0.5 when df=2

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, poisson-distribution, correlation

This should be failry intuaive,  but i cannot figure out why chi squared distribution incepet the y axis at 0.5 when df=2

Am I correct in saying the bigger the chi^2 the bigger the difference between the expected and observed and when chi^2 is sufficiently large we can reject the fact the expected and observed are the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your reasoning for using a chi^2 test is correct, a bigger chi^2 value is less likely so a large enough value would lead us to reject the null.

For df=2 the chi^2 distribution is equal to an exponential distribution with a rate parameter equal to 2. Beyond this there shouldn't be any intuitive reason why the y intercept is 0.5 because the y intercept depends on the value of the pdf across the whole distribution.

Comment: Thanks @Hugh I was hoping maybe because there is a 50% that something happens but alas!

Can i just check also that when df=1 we have the normal distribution?

Comment: @MathsWiz It's a probability density function so 0.5 isn't a 50% chance. For example, a uniform distribution between 0 and 0.5 has a probability density function of $f(x)=2$  but this isn't a 200% chance

Comment: Thanks @Hugh Can I just check then the with a 95% significance level the area of "rejection" contains 5% of the area and therefore 5% of the possible answers from the X^2=(O-E)^2/E formula. Some example don't always "look right" as the area seems too big or small.

Comment: @MathsWiz That's right, the rejection region contains the most extreme X^2 values, the probability of any of those extreme values occurring is 5%. Maybe the reason that the examples don't look right is because when you reject a hypothesis you are thinking "We are 95% sure that the alternative hypothesis is true" but that's a mistake, you should be thinking "If the null hypothesis is true there is a 5% chance of getting experiment results that are this extreme"